# Openpyxl - looking for best option to get this list, dictionaries thing sorted

Tags: python, json, excel, list, dictionary

I have a JSON file with headers (Student, Rank, City, Interest).
Here's the structure of the JSON file

```
[{"Student": "A", "Rank": 9, "City": “Milan”, "Interest": “Singing”}, {"Student": "B", "Rank": 5, "City": “NYC”, "Interest": “Problem Solving”}, {"Student": "C", "Rank": 9, "City": “Chicago”, "Interest": “Dancing”}, {"Student": "D", "Rank": 10, "City": “Boston”, "Interest": “Parasailing”}, {"Student": "E", "Rank": 9, "City": “Paris”, "Interest": “Apparel Designing”}, {"Student": "F", "Rank": 6, "City": “LA”, "Interest": “Wellness”}, {"Student": "G", "Rank": 25, "City": “Phoenix”, "Interest": “Acting”}]
```

I open this JSON file like this in my code

```
jsonfile = open("C:\\Users\Ricky\\Desktop\\StudData.json","rt")
storejsondata = json.load(jsonfile)
```

storejsondata gives me a list of dictionaries like this [{'Student': 'A', 'Rank': 9, 'City': 'Milan', 'Interest': 'Singing'}, {'Student': 'B', 'Rank': 5, 'City': 'NYC', 'Interest': 'Problem Solving'} ............]

Then I loop through this list, like this

```
for dictdata in storejsondata:
    print(dictdata)
print(type(dictdata))
```

It shows individual dictionaries from the list vertically like this
{'Student': 'A', 'Rank': 9, 'City': 'Milan', 'Interest': 'Singing'}
{'Student': 'B', 'Rank': 5, 'City': 'NYC', 'Interest': 'Problem Solving')
.....
I want to get the keys of this, I do:

```
listkey=[]
for key in xdict.keys():
     print(f'keys are: {key}')
     listkey.append(key)
print(listkey)
I write the keys as header in Excel like this
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\Rickey\\Desktop\\Studrec.xlsx")
sheet=wb.active
rows = 1
cols = 1
for i in range (0,len(listkey)):
     sheet.cell(row=rows,column=cols).value=listkey[i]
     cols=cols+1

wb.save("C:\\Users\Ricky\\Desktop\\Studrec.xlsx")
```

I can write the headers in the Excel on row 1. This works fine.

PROBLEM:

1. How can I get the values ?
   If I use:

   for key, val in datadict.items():
   print(key, val)

This only shows the vales of the last dictionary item i.e. G, 25, Phoenix, Acting. How to get values of all the dictionaries
2. How to write these values in Excel ? I want it like this -
Row 1 Col 1, Col2, Col3, Col 4 are headers
from row 2 onwards I want the values in respective columns. How to get this using Openpyxl ?

Comment: do you have to use excel? is csv format ok?

Comment: Excel is preferable. If CSV format has a simpler and a better solution, I can try this out. Thank you !

Comment: csv is MUCH simpler and you can use just standard python library, and you can open it in excel after, you could also use pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If openpyxl is not an absolute requirement you can really simplify this by either using the python standard library (`csv` and `json`) and writing to a csv or using pandas and writing to excel (or just about any other file format):

Standard Library:

```py
import json
import csv

# function to read json files into a dict or list of dicts
def read_json(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

# function to write csv files from dicts or list of dicts
def write_csv(data, path):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        fieldnames = set().union(*data)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

# load the json data
json_data = read_json('StudData.json')

write_csv(json_data, './student_data.csv')
```

Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('./StudData.json')
df.to_excel('./student_data.xlsx')
```

Output (excel screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'll try both the options. I prefer the standard python library to pandas but it's absolutely good to know that the logic is this simple and easy to follow !

Comment: I tried the two programs and it worked fine. One question though - I didn't quite understand this fieldnames = set().union(*data) .. @Tenacious B

Comment: that line takes all the possible column headers, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-function-python/